# How can I add class="required" in the following select v-model?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

```
     <div v-for="value in day" class="checkboxFour">
   <input type="checkbox" id="need" value="value.val" v-model="value.selected" style="width: 10%!important;">
 <label for="need" style=" width: 30%!important;">{{value.name}}</label>
      <select v-model="value.from" class="select-style">From
      <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
          <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
          <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
          <option value="23:00">23.00</option>
        </select>
        <select v-model="value.to" class="select-style">To
          <option value="08:00">08.00</option>
          <option value="12:00">12.00</option>
          <option value="20:00">20.00</option>
          <option value="23:00">23.00</option>
        </select>
        <br>

      </div>
```

This is select option. When I use required="". I am getting getAttribute error. How can I able to correct the same?

Also how can I use selected in the following case? My target is select a particular value previously and then user can change according to his need? Please help me to obtain the same?

Comment: Do you want to bind the [required attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_required.asp)? Or just set it? You can set it with just `required` (no `=` after it).

Comment: i need to have the required

Comment: how sir to achieve

Answer (score 0):

As it mentioned in [Vue.JS docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) you can use `v-bind:class` to achieve what you wanted:

```
<select v-model="value.from" v-bind:class="{required: isRequired}">
```

which `required` is data, computed field in your app/component.

Update 1:

```
    new Vue({
    el: "#myApp",
    data: {
        // you should define a variable in your data
        isRequired: false
    },
    methods: {
        doSomething: function(){
            this.isRequired = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: [Vue warn]: Property or method "isRequired" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

(found in <Root>)

Comment: @Wanderer, Haven't you defined a `isRequired` field in your data? I updated my answer plz take a look again.

Answer (score 0):

The [required attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_required.asp) is a boolean (an not a class). You don't need to give it a value; if it is present in the select tag, the select is required.

You can also bind it to a boolean value to change whether the select is required.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    isRequired: false
  }
});
```

```css
[required] {
  outline: thin solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select required>
    <option>An option</option>
  </select> This one is always required
  <div>
    <select :required="isRequired">
     <option>Whatever</option>
    </select>
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="isRequired"> Is Required: {{isRequired}}
  </div>
</div>
```